# Trouble in Controller Query foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello Again everyone,

can anyone help me with this code.

```
public function submitranking(Request $req){
    $dataCandidate = Candidate::all();

    foreach($dataCandidate as $Candidate){
        $judgeRate = Score::where('canId',$Candidate->id )
        ->where('catId',$req->catId )
        ->where('judgeId',$req->judgeId)
        ->sum('score');
        dd($judgeRate);
    }

}
```

It is supposed to display all the scores of the candidates when I dd($judgeRate) it only display one record? How can I make it loop and display all the total sum scores of the candidates... Please help

Comment: dd() is executing exit function. If you want to display per record. change dd to var_dump

Comment: As @jonggu said, You can't use dump to display all data inside a loop.

Comment: i think the issue is use of `sum` here. also add `group by`. i think it should work. i didn't check but it should be work at first glance

Comment: Please you should display your  **$dataCandidate** variable like:

    $dataCandidate = Candidate::all();
    
    print('<pre style="color:red;">');
    print_r($dataCandidate);
    print('</pre>');
    exit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function submitranking(Request $req){

    $dataCandidate = Candidate::get();

    foreach($dataCandidate as $Candidate){
        $judgeRate = Score::where('canId',$Candidate->id )
        ->where('catId',$req->catId )
        ->where('judgeId',$req->judgeId)
        ->sum('score');

        print('<pre style="color:red;">');
        print_r($judgeRate);
        print('</pre>');
    }
    exit;  
}
```

**OR** You should try this:

```
public function submitranking(Request $req){

    $dataCandidate = Candidate::get();

    foreach($dataCandidate as $Candidate){
        $judgeRate = Score::select('score_id',DB::raw("SUM(score) as score"))
        ->where('canId',$Candidate->id )
        ->where('catId',$req->catId )
        ->where('judgeId',$req->judgeId)
        ->get();

        print('<pre style="color:red;">');
        print_r($judgeRate);
        print('</pre>');
    }
    exit;    
}
```

Comment: @EasyWay: If my answer is your solution then please **upvote** to my Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pluck** function to get all ids of candidates and use `whereIn`.

So, there is no need to use loop, use group by and simple raw query.

Just change your function like,

```
public function submitranking(Request $req){

    $dataCandidate = Candidate::all()->pluck('canId');

    $judgeRate = Score::whereIn('canId',$dataCandidate)
                 ->where('catId',$req->catId )
                 ->where('judgeId',$req->judgeId)
                 ->select('catId',DB::raw('COUNT(score) as total_score'))
                 ->groupBy('catId')
                 ->get();
    dd($judgeRate);
}
```

You can see docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Hope you understand.

Comment: I want to loop this, with your code you remove the foreach loop.. how can I display the score each candidate?

Comment: yes.. but if you use whereIn you are sending an array and that is not what I am going to happen.. I want to display each totals scores of the specific id. the problem on my code is that the loop does not work in what I want.. it only display 1 result..

Comment: @EasyWay Okay then, you can prefer another answer added here by Add Web Solution. You can't use exit or halt state inside a loop that's a problem. This problem can be solved in many ways.